# Monitor Oracle query plans for PARTITION LIST (ALL)

Tags: oracle, partitioning

Is there any way I can monitor all the queries running on an Oracle instance and report which  queries are using `PARTITION LIST (ALL)`?

What I'm essentially asking for is a way to automatically `EXPLAIN PLAN` on every query, then search the plan results for queries that are not eliminating partitions properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a job procedure which would get all running queries:

```
SELECT sql_id, sql_child_number FROM V$SESSION WHERE SQL_ID IS NOT NULL AND TYPE='USER';
```

and then loop through that cursor and get explain plan

```
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(v_sql_id, v_sql_child_number));
```

Comment: Thanks. I could also use V$SQL for the outer loop if I wanted to monitor SQL that may not be currently running as well.